# Change video source with Javascript in html without refreshing the page just the video

Tags: javascript, html5-video

My team and I are making a custom html video player and I'm working on a setting panel
And the first option we are mainly worried about so I'm adding first is the video quality option.

```
<video id="video" class="nm" poster="the poster url">
  <source src="video source url of the video at 480p" type="video/mp4" size="480">
  <source src="video source url of the video at 720p" type="video/mp4" size="720">
  <source src="video source url of the video at 1080p" type="video/mp4" size="1080">
</video>
```

And now what we want to do is when the user toggles on an option it will change the video source to the source that has the quality specified by the `size` attribute
[Image reference here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiFCz.png)

> PS: We are making a video player from scratch as It is on its own built with no APIs (e.g. Video.js, JWPlayer, Plyr) We are making all the things needed from scratch with pure javascript and html... and as we're making a website for streaming, and my team and I want to make a video player made by us for the website, and "***maybe***" later for distribution but for now we want to make a brand new video player and were just been putting this part off as we aren't sure of the best way to do this!

### Edit

Also, we want the video to pause and change the quality and pick up off where it was paused

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the native `video` the browser will decide which `<source>` to show and choose the first element it supports/understands (e.g. the first supported video file format): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Usage_notes

To circumvent that and force the browser to show a certain video source url, put in only one `<source>` element and manipulate the source property with javascript.

To pause and play the video in the native HTML5 video player you may use the API of the `HTMLMediaElement`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement
It has the [play](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) and [pause](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause) functions you're looking for.